# Which C# connector supports embedded MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql

Do you know a .NET Connector that supports mysqld (embedded mysql)?

AFAIK the official MySQL Connector/NET doesn't support it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a OleDb connection?

Comment: I do need a connector, a real one. I've found DevArt http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ordering.html which is the only one looking good.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for it 6 months ago, this official connector doesn't exists for .NET (maybe non-free solutions provides it?)
I've used C++ connector instead in my .NET project to interact with MySQLd, it works.

Have you ever think about SqlServerCompact? .NET integration works like a charm.

Comment: I do need it to run on Linux too, although yes, we're looking into Compact Edition too...